# separate a string from some specific words in php

Tags: php, string, explode

I have a string called $metar

```
 $metar = EICK 011300Z 10004KT 27/17 Q1018 TEMPO AT0800 20006KT 010V220 9999 SCT029
```

and this string could changed every an hour depending a dynamic file.

in basic, i want to separate the $metar to two strings, the separate point is "AT0800"

```
list($a, $b) = explode(' AT0800 ', $metar);
echo $b;
```

but the problem is the "AT0800" could change to "AT1200" or "AT1900" in the future, the only words are keep is the "AT", So how can i get the string $b which is after the word "ATxxxx" ? Thanks

Comment: The ATXXXX digit can change like ATXXXXXXXX or is this static 4 digit?
ATXXXX come 7th position in meter or that also will change like EICK ATXXXX 011300Z 27/17 ..?

Comment: If ATXXXX will always have the same pattern, you just can make a substring.

Comment: Pilot here - for clarification, the `0800` in `AT0800` is 0800 Zulu - 24-hr time. So the range will be `0000` through `2399`. 4 digits always.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split the string with `AT####` using a regex:

```
$metar_split = preg_split('/AT[0-9]{4}/', $metar);
```

The first half:

```
echo trim($metar_split[0]);
```

The second half (the one you're looking for):

```
$b = trim($metar_split[1]);
```

To get the `AT####` portion:

```
preg_match('/AT[0-9]{4}/', $metar, $matches);
$metar_at = $matches[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

If the position of ATxxxx in the string is always fixed (and the number of characters before it are also fixed), and xxxx always means 4 digits, then you could just go and use `substr` to select the desired segment of the string, as in:

```
$part1 = substr($metar, 0, 38);
$part2 = substr($metar, 46);
```

However, if you are looking at a varying lengths for the rest of the content, yet ATxxxx format is expected, you could have at it with a regular expression along the lines of:

```
([\w\s\/]+) AT[0-9]{4} ([\w\s\/]+)
```

This will grab out your two parts, which are seperated by the letters AT and exactly 4 digits. The `[\w\s\/]+` part says: "grab me word characters (letters and numbers), white spaces and slash characters at least one, or any number more".

Answer (score 0):

here you go, the answer is attached below:

```
       list($a, $b) = explode('AT', $metar, 2);
        //echo $b;
        list($c, $d) = explode(' ', $b, 2);
        //echo $d;
```

Comment: That's a pretty roundabout way. Try my new edit before you accept this as your answer in a few days.